# Hackerrank with Python 3.x.x code does not work

Tags: python

I am trying to do some exercises in hackerrank with python. While i code with pyCharm everything seems to work, but in the hackerrank editor i get errors, for example:

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5]
k = input()

def findNumber(arr, k):
    if k in arr:
        print('YES')
    else: print('NO')
findNumber(arr, k)
```

I don't understand how should I code on the hackerrank editor in a way that their input works with my algorithm

thanks for any help

Comment: what Errors do you get? Is hackerRank using Python 2 or 3?

Comment: you should probably be returning something instead of printing it.

Comment: Runtime error. In my code snippet i created an array so that my function has an input, but on hackerrank they have their own input, which is a multiple row set of int.

Comment: If you're using Python 3 as you suggest in your title then this won't work. `input` will return a string and it won't match anything in your list.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ what can I return in order to also have 'YES' and 'NO' printed?

Comment: Where's the link to the problem on the site?

Comment: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/find-digits/problem

Comment: It's not exactly this one, I can't find the same challenge, but it's very similar to this one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of printing the output try to return the output

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5]
k = input()

def findNumber(arr, k):
    if k in arr:
        return 'YES'
    else: return 'NO'
findNumber(arr, k)
```

Answer (score 0):

As we know that function always return something. So, if we use return instead of print function then that will be very professional and efficient.

```
 arr=[1,2,3,4,5]
    k=int(input())
    def findnumber(arr,k):
        if k in arr:
           return 'YES'
        else:
          return 'NO'
    findnumber(arr,k)
```

Comment: Code only answers sometimes are not very helpful